# Help identifying Lego bag without instructions, brown, grey, and clear bricks

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help identify which set this bag comes from?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bag from the Minecraft set [First Night (21115)](http://brickset.com/sets/21115-1/The-First-Night):

[image: First Night]

Comment: Ooo... that brings back good memories.